# wxPython : change colour of a DataViewListCtrl item

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxwidgets, wxpython

I'm pretty new to building UIs, so I apologize if my question seems dumb in any way.

I'm currently building a small interface which aims at displaying a report depending on several entry parameters.

At first, I wanted the report to be shown through a *wxListCtrl* (LC_REPORT) but the problem I encountered is that I can't set the background or the font colour of a "Cell", I can only do it for the complete row. Maybe I'm mistaken tho.

Secondly, I found that I could show a report in a *wxDataViewListCtrl*, but I must admit I'm kind of lost within wxPython documentation (wxDataViewItem, wxDataViewItemAttr, etc).

Is there a way, once I built the report, to change some cells settings specifically?

Comment: The wxDataViewCtrl is complex and not well explained. Setting a background color for just a "cell" is anything but easy. I suggest to use a `wxGrid`. While it's also complex, it's much more easy to understand and deal with.

Comment: I might consider to do this, since I already used a *wxGrid* for another tool. But IIRC, in this case the first column is always not "editable", is it?

Comment: @ThylowZ, what do you mean by first column?

Comment: If you are going to report in a table format with some additional text formatting, as suggested `wxGrid` is a good choice.

Comment: @Igor, sorry, I don't know how to explain it better, but last time I used *wxGrid* I had, by default, a first column which was sort of a "vertical header" (sorry I'm not native english) ==> I had both a vertical and a horizontal "header".
Here, I need all my columns to be identical format-wise, in the same way as a listbox report.
Dunno if it's more clear...

Comment: @ThylowZ, you can hide the column header and/or row header. Just check the documentation on the wx.Grid for appropriate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do what you want using the UltimateListCtrl widget. The wxPython demo even has an example of setting a single cell's background color to yellow. It looks like  the items are of the following type: `UltimateListItem`. These have a `_colour` property that can be set.

The `ObjectListView` also might be a solution that is worth looking at: https://objectlistview-python-edition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#how-can-i-change-the-colours-of-a-row